# regex expression to match but exclude from result

Tags: java, regex

Hi i have the following text in log file

```
projectId:1 name:John
projectId:63232 name:Sam
telno:0232453242323
```

The regex expression should only return

```
1
63232
```

Currently i've got the following regex projectId:\d* which unwantedly matches the 'projectId:'. How do i omit that from final matches?

Using the solution given in java

```
    String term = "ProjectId:11414084 Title:Recherche partenariat";
    String regex = "(?<=ProjectId:)\\d*";

    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = r.matcher(term);
    m.matches();
    m.group();
```

The following throw exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:536)
at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:496)
```

Comment: Try: `projectId:([0-9]+)`

Answer (score 2):

Just use the global identifier which does not return on first match.

Depending on the programming language you use, there are different ways to use the global flag. If you tell us more about the usage, I could give you further information on how to.

I see you updated your question.

For only retrieving the number use the positive lookbehind like this:

```
(?<=projectId:)\d*
```

[Here a regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/bL9kP4/3)

Answer (score 1):

Use [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?<=projectId:)\d+
```

Look-aheads and look-behinds let you conditionally match items without becoming part of the match themselves.

[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/tS4fH8/1)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than *excluding* anything from a match, you may *capture* some specific part of it using a pair of unescaped parentheses:

```
\bprojectId:(\d*)
            ^   ^
```

or - if there must be at least one digit:

```
\bprojectId:(\d+)
               ^
```

Now, **the value  you need is in Group 1**. See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eV4hB4/1).

Note I added `\b` that is a word boundary, `nonproject:234` won't get matched now.

See [more about *capturing groups*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) here.